# Can I run Arduino code on a 6502?

Tags: arduino-ide, library, eeprom

I've been doing projects with the arduino boards for a long time and accordingly also with the libs from adafruit etc. But that was too boring for me and I wanted to get more into the matter, so I used youtube and acquired knowledge about the microcontrollers eeproms etc. itself . But now my question is whether I, if I have the necessary interface adapters, etc., can compile the libs from adafruit, etc. and flash the hex file directly onto an eeprom and then use it with e.g. connect and use a 6502. but I need the corresponding settings in the IDE so that the code can be executed correctly, right? and what is the best way to do this? and general tips would also be nice thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps the results of a search for "6502 vs avr" would be enlightening.

Comment: your question is same as `can I speak Swahili to an Englishman and be clearly understood?`

Comment: Maybe yes on a C++ level but you have to write the tool chain and all the needed files. That would including all the libraries you use. In about 20 years you may have enough done to start testing.  As far as flasining, if my memory is correct it has no RAM or FLASH so you will also have to design the chip.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

You would fail at the first hurdle: you would need to find a 6502 C++ compiler, and AFAICT there is no such thing.

Without a C++ compiler for the 6502 you would never be able to compile C++ code for the 6502.

The closest you would come is to program in pure C for the 6502, which means you won't be able to use 99% of the Arduino libraries (not counting the fact that many use architecture-specific register access) since they are written in C++ not in C.